# XSL key matching one or more child nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a complex XML file structured by book title. Something like this, but with hundreds of books and sometimes many authors per book.

```
<Book>
    <Title>Ken Lum</Title>
    <Author>
        <GivenName>Grant</GivenName>
        <Surname>Arnold</Surname>
    </Author>
</Book>
<Book>
    <Title>Shore, Forest and Beyond</Title>
    <Author>
        <GivenName>Ian M.</GivenName>
        <Surname>Thom</Surname>
    </Author>
    <Author>
        <GivenName>Grant</GivenName>
        <Surname>Arnold</Surname>
    </Author>
</Book>
```

What I need to output is an alphabetized list of authors, and then a list of every book they worked on, also alphabetized, something like:

> Arnold, Grant — Ken Lum; Shore, Forest and Beyond
>
> Thom, Ian M. — Shore, Forest and Beyond

I have a version of the code working fairly well, but it is very slow, so I'm trying to optimize my approach. I recently learned of the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) of grouping from another user here and I'm trying to apply that.

The part I'm specifically stuck on right now is getting the list of titles per author. This is what I have right now:

```
<xsl:key name="books-by-author" match="Book"
         use="concat(Author/GivenName, Contributor/Surname)" />
…
<xsl:template match="Author">
    …
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="ByAuthor" select=
                                "key('books-by-author',
                                     concat(GivenName, Surname)
                                     )">
        <xsl:sort select="Title/TitleText"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</template>
```

But it seems that this is only matching Books where the Author is the first one listed, like:

> Arnold, Grant — Ken Lum
>
> Thom, Ian M. — Shore, Forest and Beyond

I figure the `xsl:key` is only using the first `Author` element, rather than checking every author. Is it possible to check every `Author` like that? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Do note that this is a limitation from XPath 1.0 where there is no concept of sequence, thus a compound key in a many to one relationship will result into an scalar value. If the key is already in one node, then it is posible to have a many to one relationship selecting those nodes. In XSLT 2.0+ with XPath 2.0+ you have the sequence concept and this problem vanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you look at this way:

**XML**

```
<Books>
    <Book>
        <Title>Ken Lum</Title>
        <Author>
            <GivenName>Grant</GivenName>
            <Surname>Arnold</Surname>
        </Author>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Title>Shore, Forest and Beyond</Title>
        <Author>
            <GivenName>Ian M.</GivenName>
            <Surname>Thom</Surname>
        </Author>
        <Author>
            <GivenName>Grant</GivenName>
            <Surname>Arnold</Surname>
        </Author>
    </Book>
</Books>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="author" match="Author" use="concat(Surname, ', ', GivenName)" />

<xsl:template match="/Books">   
    <Authors>
        <!-- for each unique author -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Book/Author[count(. | key('author', concat(Surname, ', ', GivenName))[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="Surname"/>
            <xsl:sort select="GivenName"/>
            <Author>
                <!-- author's details-->
                <xsl:copy-of select="Surname | GivenName"/>
                <!-- list author's books -->
                <Books>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('author', concat(Surname, ', ', GivenName))/parent::Book">
                        <xsl:sort select="Title"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Title"/>
                    </xsl:for-each> 
                </Books>
            </Author>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Authors>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Authors>
  <Author>
    <GivenName>Grant</GivenName>
    <Surname>Arnold</Surname>
    <Books>
      <Title>Ken Lum</Title>
      <Title>Shore, Forest and Beyond</Title>
    </Books>
  </Author>
  <Author>
    <GivenName>Ian M.</GivenName>
    <Surname>Thom</Surname>
    <Books>
      <Title>Shore, Forest and Beyond</Title>
    </Books>
  </Author>
</Authors>
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew there had to be a better approach. This is going so much faster than my previous versions of the code!